# org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Variable Resource Not Found using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-remotedriver

I am using the phantomjs webdriver using selenium protocol to render the webpage.When I try to render the webpage ,I am getting the following error in

```
RemoteWebDriver.get(url)
```

method eventhough my webdriver is running.

I have also tried restarting the phantomjs webdriver.

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Variable Resource Not Found - {"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"39","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"10.20.1.239:9517","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_171)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"url\":\"http://example.com/\"}","url":"/session/07e53c90-6b45-11e9-892c-4faf7180871b/url","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"url","directory":"/session/07e53c90-6b45-11e9-892c-4faf7180871b/","path":"/session/07e53c90-6b45-11e9-892c-4faf7180871b/url","relative":"/session/07e53c90-6b45-11e9-892c-4faf7180871b/url","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/session/07e53c90-6b45-11e9-892c-4faf7180871b/url","queryKey":{},"chunks":["session","07e53c90-6b45-11e9-892c-4faf7180871b","url"]}}
Command duration or timeout: 10.20 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ip-10-20-1-73.ec2.internal', ip: '10.20.1.73', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=false, databaseEnabled=false, version=2.1.1, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy=Proxy(direct), nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, driverVersion=1.2.0, locationContextEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false, browserName=phantomjs, takesScreenshot=true, driverName=ghostdriver, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 07e53c90-6b45-11e9-892c-4faf7180871b
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at
```

Comment: what is the URL you are trying to get? can you share your entire code? (how you create the driver etc.) what is the phantomjs driver version you are using? what is the selenium server version ?

Comment: try read this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/6HIIB5AI010

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.The URL differs from time to time.The error occurs for all the URLs. Phantomjs version is 2.1.1 and selenium version is 2.52.0.We create the driver in following way. new RemoteWebDriver(new URL( cdaddress), capabilities);

Answer (score 2):

**RemoteWebDriver** is a keyword/researved word. So instances of **RemoteWebDriver** should be differently named. Additionally while invoking *RemoteWebDriver* you need to pass the `URL` of the *Selenium Grid Hub*  and the instance of `DesiredCapabilities` as mandatory arguments and you can use the following (*Windows* based) solution:

```
File path=new File("C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",path.getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.XXX);         
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```